# Do commutative matrices share the same eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let two square matrices $A$ and $B$ represent linear operators on a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose they are commutative. Then

$$ABx=BAx,\,\,\forall x\in V$$

Then let $\tilde{x}$ be an eigenvector of $B$. Setting, $x=\tilde{x}$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
AB\tilde{x}&=BA\tilde{x}\\
A\lambda \tilde{x} &= BA\tilde{x},\,\,\exists \lambda\in\mathbb{C}\\
\lambda (A\tilde{x}) &= B(A\tilde{x})\\
&\\
\implies A\tilde{x}&=\alpha\tilde{x},\,\,\exists \alpha\in\mathbb{C}
\end{align}$$

So every eigenvector of $B$ is also an eigenvector of $A$. $\blacksquare$

**MY QUESTIONS:** Is this valid? If it isn't, what have I done wrong? If it is, does this mean that the two matrices are similar by the matrix formed by making each column an eigenvector of the two matrices?

Comment: How do you derive that $A\bar{x}=\alpha\bar{x}$? What you have proved is that $A\bar{x}$ belongs to the eigenspace of $B$ relative to $\lambda$, but this not necessarily means it's a scalar multiple of $\bar{x}$.

Comment: Then what does it mean for every vector in a subspace to belong to a particular eigenspace (where they have the same dimension)? $\{A\tilde{x}|\,\forall\tilde{x}\in\textrm{eigenspace relative to }\lambda\}$ is a subspace of dimension $1$, and so if every element of it is within the eigenspace of $B$ relative to $\lambda$, which is also of dimension $1$, then the two subspaces must be isomorphic. Hence, every $A\tilde{x}$ is equal to some element of the eigenspace of $B$ relative to $\lambda$, so it is equal to some multiple of $\tilde{x}$.

Comment: Why should the eigenspace of $B$ relative to $\lambda$ have dimension $1$? And why should $\{A\bar{x}:B\bar{x}=\lambda x\}$ have dimension $1$?

Comment: I incorrectly assumed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's obviously false. The identity matrix commutes with every other matrix, but any nonzero vector is an eigenvector for the identity, which can be not true for a non identity matrix.

Comment: Good point. If we were to further restrain the matrices $A$ and $B$ and require them to both be diagonalizable, would @Qidi's statement hold? (I would think yes)

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan Yes, that's quite a deep theorem.

Comment: How so? (I won't further this conversation after your response)

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan The proof is not very hard. You first decompose $V$ into a sum of eigenspaces of $A$, then show that this decomposition is stabilized under $B$. Then you can refine the decomposition to diagonalize $B$. Using induction the proof works for a finite set of commuting diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: @Qidi I was thinking exactly that. Thanks for your answer by the way!

Answer (score 1):

What is true though, is that there is a basis $\{b_i\}$ of $V$ such that $b_i$ are eigenvectors of both $A$ and $B$.(Given they are diagonalizable)

Comment: I'm not sure. In general, commuting matrices are simultaneously triangularizable (over $\mathbb{C}$ or an algebraically closed field). Existence of a basis of eigenvectors is equivalent to diagonalizability.

Comment: @egreg Yeah you're right, here I assumed $A$,$B$ were diagonalizable.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is true. May be $P$ the Matrix of all eigenvectors and $diag([\lambda])$ the diagonal Matrix of all Eigenvalues $\lambda$. Then $A=P^Tdiag([\alpha])P$ and $B=P^Tdiag([\lambda])P$. These matrices are similar; only the Eigenvalue spectrum can differ.